# User and its data is undefined on the context.switchToHttp().getRequest() with nestjs guards

Tags: nestjs

I'm new to nestJs and I needed to add role based access to the application so I followed the documentation but in the execution context user doesn't exist. I can't seems to find the problem
here is the full repo https://github.com/callme-MJ/test-sample

**roles.guard.ts**

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Reflector } from "@nestjs/core";
import { use } from "passport";
import { Role } from "src/typeorm/roles.enum";

@Injectable()
    export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate{
        constructor (private reflector:Reflector){}

        canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
            const requiredRole = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<Role[]>('roles',[
                context.getHandler(),
                context.getClass(),
            ]);
            if (!requiredRole) {
                return true
            }
            const {user} = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
            

            return requiredRole.some((role)=> user.role.includes(role));
              }
    }
```

**auth.controller.ts**

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Request, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from 'src/auth/services/auth/auth.service';
import { Role } from 'src/typeorm/roles.enum';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from 'src/utils/guards/jwt.auth.guard';
import { LocalAuthGuard } from 'src/utils/guards/local-auth.guards';
import { RolesGuard } from 'src/utils/guards/roles.guards';
import { Roles } from 'src/utils/roles.decorator';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) { }

  

  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard,RolesGuard)
  @Get('dashboard')
  @Roles(Role.CORDINATOR)
  getResponse(@Request() req): any {
    return req.user;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[At this line in your repo](https://github.com/callme-MJ/test-sample/blob/cabc9707585598ac41bdb1be7fa49f295060593e/src/auth/auth.module.ts#L16) you have `APP_GUARD` which is a **global** guard binding. This means that *this* `RolesGuard` will be registered and used before your `JwtAuthGuard` in the `getResponse` method of the `AuthController`. [Take a look at the section on "Enabling Authentication Globally"](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#enable-authentication-globally) for a way around this. Otherwise, you can remove the `APP_GUARD` for the `RolesGuard` and just bind it where necessar

Comment: if i remove RolesGuard from being globally , can i use RolesGuard without jwtGuard on some specific routes.....?

Comment: How would the `RolesGuard` work with the `JwtGuard`? Your `JwtGuard` is what calls to `passport` which is what populates `req.user`

Comment: ok thank you. your help was really appreciated .iam new to nestjs and it was a great relief for me.

 you did mean "without JwtGuard"  in the previous comment, right?

Comment: Yes, typing too fast and thinking of too many things at once.